# How far can we get without a foundation, using just first-order logic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, foundations

I think its interesting to ask how far we can get without committing to any particular foundations, using just first-order logic.

For instance, we can prove theorems in this way about partially ordered sets, groups, fields etc. by just going straight from the axioms.

Okay, now suppose we have two partially ordered sets $P$ and $Q$ and an order-preserving function $f : P \rightarrow Q$. **Even without any model theory, we can still reason about this configuration**.

We do this by forming a new first-order theory, whose domain of discourse can be viewed as being $P \cup Q$ (or a superset thereof). Formally, our signature includes two unary predicates $P$ and $Q$, where $P(x)$ can be read '$x$ belongs to $P$' and $Q(x)$ can be read '$x$ belongs to $Q$.' More suggestively, lets write $x \in P$ and $x \in Q$ to mean $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ respectively. We also need a unary function symbol $f$ together with the axiom

$$\forall x \in P : f(x) \in Q$$

Also, we need a relation symbol $\leq$. To express that $f$ is order-preserving, we assume:

$$\forall x,y \in P : x \leq y \Rightarrow f(x) \leq f(y)$$

Finally, we must assume that the axioms of a partially ordered set hold when relativized to $P$, and also to $Q$. This amounts to six different axioms.

1. $\forall x \in P : x \leq x$
2. $\forall x,y \in P : x \leq y, y \leq x \Rightarrow x=y$
3. $\forall x,y,z \in P : x \leq y, y \leq z \Rightarrow x \leq z$
4. $\forall x \in Q : x \leq x$
5. $\forall x,y \in Q : x \leq y, y \leq x \Rightarrow x=y$
6. $\forall x,y,z \in Q : x \leq y, y \leq z \Rightarrow x \leq z$

Okay, that's the setup. Using the formal system we just constructed, we can reason about the configuration $f : P \rightarrow Q,$ where $f$ is an order-preserving function and $P$ and $Q$ are partially ordered sets.

So my question is: *how far can we get in this way, without committing to any particular foundations, and at what point do we hit a brick wall?*

Comment: Very few of the standard important results about groups, fields can be expressed, let alone proved, in the usual first-order axiomatizations of group theory/field theory. (The situation with number theory is different.)

Comment: How can you define (order-preserving) *function* without any set theory (foundation)??

Comment: How do you know that you are reasoning *about anything* without a foundation? E.g. how do you know that there exist things called partially ordered sets, groups, fields, etc. without constructing some?

Comment: @Berci, I have edited the question to try to make it clearer. Hopefully, its better now.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, we don't! But even with a foundations, we have this same problem, since after all, it might be inconsistent.

Comment: @user: we have a different problem. With a foundations, we know that we're okay if our foundations are consistent. Without a foundations, we need to ask the question *separately*, for *each kind of thing we want to reason about*, whether the axioms describing those things are consistent.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, yes I agree, but I'd say it a bit differently. With a foundations, we still need to ask the question separately for each kind of thing we want to reason about, but luckily our foundations should allow us to answer the question. Without a foundations, there's simply no way of getting an answer. Okay, but so what? At what point does this actually become a problem?

Comment: The problem, I think, that @Qiaochu is pointing out is that we *don't know that group theory is consistent*. We do know that if $\sf ZFC$ is consistent then group theory is consistent. But even if prove that, what about abelian groups? is that a consistent theory? What about simple abelian groups? What about ring theory? What about field theory? What about algebraically closed fields of characteristics $3$? In $\sf ZFC$ we can prove that these have models, and conclude their consistency. Otherwise you have to work very very hard (I don't even know if you can) showing each theory is consistent.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, yes. But the point I was trying to make (reading over my comment, I did not make the point very eloquently) is: okay suppose we don't know whether or not group theory is consistent. So what? We can still prove theorems in the language of groups. We can still prove things about group homomorphisms. At what point does our inability to prove that there exists a group become a problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The original question is perhaps not very clear, but the OP's responses to comments suggest the following two remarks could be relevant:

1. Suppose I specify  a set of first-order sentences $\Sigma$. I can indeed explore what follows from $\Sigma$ by using first-order reasoning, without knowing in advance whether $\Sigma$ is a consistent set. (Of course, one thing that I can discover is that for some $\varphi$, we have both  $\Sigma \vdash \varphi$ and $\Sigma \vdash \neg\varphi$, so that $\Sigma$ is actually, after all, inconsistent.) To this extent, we can indeed explore the theory whose axioms are $\Sigma$ without presupposing a "foundation" (i.e. without recourse to a background theory which we can use to model the axioms).
2. OK, suppose things have gone swimmingly so far: I've deduced lots of  propositions from $\Sigma$. I conjecture that some $\sigma$ also follows. But try as I might, I can't get a proof. So I lose confidence. How can I show that indeed $\Sigma \nvdash \sigma$? Well, a standard method is to come up with a model with satisfies $\Sigma$ but not $\sigma$. But *now* I do need *some* background theory in which I can do some model-building. Maybe I can find a countermodel to $\Sigma \vdash \sigma$  in some relatively tame structure (the naturals or the reals). If I need something more exotic, ZFC gives me a sort of all-purpose Lego-kit for building mathematical structures. But we'll need *some* source of models.

In sum: while investigating what $\Sigma$ *does* entail "just" requires logic, to investigate what $\Sigma$ *doesn't* entail we will often need to appeal to some substantive background theory (if you like, a relatively "foundational" theory).

Comment: Great example! How do you prove that group theory neither proves nor disproves $\forall x\forall y(x\cdot y=y\cdot x)$, without some model theoretical foundations?

Comment: All purpose Lego-kit? +1.

Comment: Peter Smith and @AsafKaragila, out of curiosity, how strong of a foundations do we need to carry out the argument that, okay, we can write down the multiplication table for the group $S_3,$ which is a group that is not Abelian, so therefore we cannot deduce $\forall x\forall y(xy=yx)$ from the group axioms?

Comment: @user18921: How do you prove that group theory is consistent? If you can't prove that, how can you prove that you can't prove something from those axioms?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, yes good point. Okay, but we can write out the multiplication table for the trivial group. So, we'd like to conclude the consistency of group theory. In general, if we can describe a finite model of a system of first-order axioms over a finite signature, we'd like to be able to conclude that the system of axioms is consistent. So, out of curiosity, how powerful of a foundations do we to do this?

Comment: @user18921: Why would that be sufficient to conclude the consistency of group theory? Because it has a model? Why isn't that an appeal to semantics, which essentially is an appeal to set theory?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, not really. Just because ZFC allows us to prove consistency under these circumstances, this does not mean ZFC is necessary to do so. I think its an interesting question of whether there is a very minimal foundational system which is just powerful enough to carry out these kinds of proofs.

Comment: @user18921: Of course. It's a good question too, and I don't know the answer. But if you appeal to "oh, we can write a multiplication table" it sounds to me that you implicitly invoke some completeness argument which invariably makes an appeal to something stronger than just syntactic manipulations.